# Laravel API endpoints not working for server alias

Tags: php, laravel, apache

I have Laravel installed on a server alias and the URL will be like

```
https://app.actualurl.com/test
```

and files are in `var/www/html/test` folder. I am accessing the website using

`https://app.actualurl.com/test/index.php`

so for login, I need to access

`https://app.actualurl.com/test/index.php/login`.

It is working fine. But now I am trying to access some `API` routes there. There is one default api route configured in `routes/api.php` and it is for the user.I tried to access the route, it is showing `Error: connect ETIMEDOUT` I tried the following URLs:

`https://app.actualurl.com/test/index.php/user` and

`https://app.actualurl.com/test/index.php/api/user`

In my local the URLs are working fine. I don't have any alias setup in the local and so it will be plain URLs like `localhost/api/user` and it is showing response.

I am using Apache2 and the alias configuration is in the `httpd.conf` file

Comment: what `https://app.actualurl.com/test/login` gives?

Comment: It will not resolve. Only from `index.php` , the URL starts resolving